# Number of sequences $(a_1, . . . , a_n)$, with elements from the set $\{ 0, 1, 2 \}$, satisfying: $|a_k - a_{k-1}| \leq 1$ for $k = 2, 3, . . ., n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Determine the number of sequences $(a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n)$, with elements from the set $\{ 0, 1, 2 \}$, satisfying the condition $|a_k - a_{k-1}| \leq 1$ for $k = 2, 3, . . ., n$.

We know that if I define the number of sequences for a given $n$ as $a_n$, then:
$$a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-1} = a_n = 7a_{n-1}$$

The equality holds because if we know that:

- the last element was equal to $1$, then semi-last element could be equal to: $0$, $1$ or $2$, so we have $3$ options
- the last element was equal to $0$, then semi-last element could be equal to: $0$ or $1$, so we have $2$ options
- the last element was equal to $2$, then semi-last element could be equal to: $1$ or $2$, so we have $2$ options

From that we have:
$$a_n = k \cdot 7^n$$

We know that $a_1 = 3$, because that one element can be equal to: $0$, $1$ or $2$, so we have $3$ options. Therefore:

$$a_n = \frac{3}{7} \cdot 7^n = 3 \cdot 7^{n-1}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: I suggest that you write down all sequences for $n=3$ ...

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for help! Now I see that it doesn't work even for n = 2. There should be $7$ such sequences $(00, 01, 10, 11, 12, 22, 21)$ and my formula gives $21$. I need to think a bit how to fix that.

Comment: It seems to me that you want to create sequence of $b_n, c_n, d_n$ which count valid sequences where the last digit is $0, 1, 2$. Then, $b_{n+1} = b_n + c_n$, $c_{n+1} = b_n + c_n + d_n, d_{n+1}  = c_n + d_n$. Can you proceed from here to find $ a_n = b_n + c_n + d_n $?

Comment: An equivalent problem with the same solution: [Strings of length $n$ formed by $a,b,c$ where $a$ and $b$ are not adjacent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2942328/42969)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution which is simpler.

Denote $(A_n,B_n,C_n)$  the number of sequences for a given $n$ that begins with $0$, $1$ or $2$. We observe that:
$$\begin{align}
&A_{n+1} = A_n + B_n\\
&B_{n+1} = A_n + B_n+C_n\tag{1}\\
&C_{n+1} = B_n +C_n\\
\end{align}$$

Denote $P(n)$ the total number of sequences of length $n$, then $P(n) = A_n + B_n +C_n$. From $(1)$, we have:

$$P(n+1) = A_{n+1}+B_{n+1} +C_{n+1} = 2\underbrace{(A_n + B_n+C_n)}_{= P(n)} + \underbrace{B_n}_{= A_{n-1}+B_{n-1} +C_{n-1} =  P(n-1)}$$
$$\implies \color{red}{P(n+1) = 2P(n) +P(n-1)} \tag{2}$$
It's easy to solve the quadratic sequence $(2)$: if $x_{1,2}= (1\pm \sqrt{2})/2$ the two solutions of the quadratic equation $x^2 - 2x -1 =0$ then $$P(n) = p_1\cdot x_1^{n}+p_2\cdot x_2 ^n \tag{3}$$

Determine $(p_1,p_2)$ from $(3)$ given that $P(1) = 3$ and $P(2) = 7$, we can show that
$$\color{red}{P(n) = \frac{(\sqrt{2}+1)^{n+1}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{2}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Denote $(A_n,B_n,C_n)$  the number of sequences for a given $n$ that begins with $0$, $1$ or $2$. We observe that:
$$\begin{align}
&A_{n+1} = A_n + B_n\\
&B_{n+1} = A_n + B_n+C_n\tag{1}\\
&C_{n+1} = B_n +C_n\\
\end{align}$$
Write $(1)$ in matrix form:
$$\underbrace{\pmatrix{A_{n+1}\\B_{n+1}\\C_{n+1}}}_{:=X_{n+1}}= \underbrace{\pmatrix{1&1&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&1}}_{:=M}\cdot\underbrace{\pmatrix{A_{n}\\B_{n}\\C_{n}}}_{:=X_{n}}$$
Diagonalize $M=U^{-1}DU$ where
$$\begin{align}
&U=\pmatrix{1&\sqrt{2}&1\\-1&0&1\\1&-\sqrt{2}&1}\\
&D=\pmatrix{1 + \sqrt{2}&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 - \sqrt{2}}\end{align}$$
Then
$$(2)\iff X_{n+1} = U^{-1}D UX_n\iff (UX_{n+1})=D\cdot (UX_n)=...=D^n\cdot (UX_1)$$
$$\implies X_n = U^{-1}D^{n-1}U X_1 = U^{-1}\cdot \pmatrix{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{n-1} &0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&(-1)^{n-1}(\sqrt{2} - 1)^{n-1}}\cdot U\cdot X_1 $$
If we denote $t = 1+\sqrt 2$ and $v = (-1)^{n-1}$ then thanks to WolframAlpha, the matrix $\Lambda_n:= U^{-1}D^{n-1}U \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ can be [computed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B1%2F4%2C%20-%281%2F2%29%2C%201%2F4%7D%2C%20%7B1%2F%282%20Sqrt%5B2%5D%29%2C%200%2C%20-%281%2F%282%20Sqrt%5B2%5D%29%29%7D%2C%20%7B1%2F4%2C%201%2F2%2C%20%20%20%201%2F4%7D%7D.%20%7B%7Bt%2C%200%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%201%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%200%2C%20v%2Ft%7D%7D.%20%7B%7B1%2C%20Sqrt%5B2%5D%2C%201%7D%2C%20%7B-1%2C%200%2C%201%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C%20-Sqrt%5B2%5D%2C%201%7D%7D) easily.

$$X_n = \Lambda_n X_1  \tag{2}$$

As $X_1 =(1,1,1)'$, $A_n,B_n,C_n$ are equal to the sum of the row of $\Lambda_n$.
And if we denote the number of sequences for a given $n$ by $P(n)$,  we have $P(n) = A_n + B_n + C_n$, then $P(n)$ is equal to the sum of all elements of $\Lambda_n$ (the matrix $\Lambda_n$ can be found in the link WolframAlpha):
$$\color{red}{P(n) = \frac{(\sqrt{2}+1)^{n+1}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{2}}$$
*Remark*: We can compute the sum via WolframAlpha by $\mathbb{1}'\cdot \Lambda_n\cdot \mathbb{1}$ (where $\mathbb{1} = (1,1,1)'$) as in this [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D.%7B%7B1%2F4%2C%20-%281%2F2%29%2C%201%2F4%7D%2C%20%7B1%2F%282%20Sqrt%5B2%5D%29%2C%200%2C%20-%281%2F%282%20Sqrt%5B2%5D%29%29%7D%2C%20%7B1%2F4%2C%201%2F2%2C%20%20%20%201%2F4%7D%7D.%20%7B%7Bt%2C%200%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%201%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%200%2C%20v%2Ft%7D%7D.%20%7B%7B1%2C%20Sqrt%5B2%5D%2C%201%7D%2C%20%7B-1%2C%200%2C%201%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C%20-Sqrt%5B2%5D%2C%201%7D%7D.%7B%7B1%7D%2C%7B1%7D%2C%7B1%7D%7D).

Comment: There is an index error in the matrix form in $X_n$

Comment: @SoumikMukherjee the index error is in which formula?

Comment: $A_n,B_n,C_n$ instead of $A_{n+1},B_{n+1},C_{n+1}$ in the rhs of the matrix form

Comment: @SoumikMukherjee Ah yes, I copied the formula and forgot to change the index. Just corrected.